# Нужно ли здесь выделять запятыми "в самом деле"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> Александр Трифонович написал пронизывающие душу строки, даже кажется, что он в самом деле знал, что случилось с тем мальчишкой.

Comment: "В самом деле" является членом предложения, выражение можно заменить - на самом деле, действительно, поэтому запятые не требуются.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Не очень понятное объяснение.  "В самом деле" и  "действительно" могут быть как вводными словами, так и наречиями, причем  в обоих функциях замена возможна. Как тогда определить, что это за функция. Вероятно, надо искать другие объяснения.